# Trying to estimate sine by using Maclaurin Series using Persistent Function

Tags: matlab, estimation, taylor-series

I have been attempting to estimate sine. The idea is that I manually press run a few times until I get the first 5 significant figures of sine correct. I do not what to use loop yet. I think I've got somewhere but I'm not sure why is is not working properly. I tried to Sin_series(1) however the following iterations are not right as they do not go towards 0.8415. I tried to add in the each derivative in as each is one of 3 possibilities: 0,1,-1. Help will be gladly appreciated.

```
function sinx = Sin_series(x) 
   persistent n sin;

   if isempty(n) || isempty(sin)

      n = 0;
      sin = 0;
   else
      n = n+1;
      if mod(n,4)==1
          sin = 0;
      elseif mod(n,4)==0 
          sin = -1;
      elseif mod(n,4)==2
          sin = 1;
      elseif mod(n,4)==3
          sin = 0;
      end
      sin = sin+x^n/factorial(n);
   end
   sinx = sin;
end
```

Comment: Where is your `loop`?

Comment: I did not want to use a loop, I've not got to that chapter yet! :/

Comment: The maclaurin series is an infinite summation. In a digital computer code, we calculate an approximation to this summation with a finite number of terms of the series. Without any loop, you cannot calculate an approximation for the sine function. How do you expect your code to work without a loop?

Comment: So you need to write more terms of the series.